# Solution to Recurrence Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, eulers-method

I have to use $20$ steps of size $h=0.5$ to estimate $y(11)$ for the curve of $y' = x-y$, going through $y(1)=1$.

Now, I could just solve the differential equation, but there will be harder differential equations in the future.

I write this as a recurrence relation. I let $a_{n+1}$ be the next step's $y$, $a_n$ be the current $y$, and let $1+\frac{n}{2}$ be x, because I am using  a step size of $0.5$, and my first $x$ is $1$.

So, I should have $y_2=hy'+y$.

Plugging in my variables, this gives me $a_{n+1}=0.5(1+\frac{n}{2}-a_n)+a_n.$

Now, I simplify to get $a_{n+1}=0.5+\frac{n}{4}+\frac{a_n}{2}=\frac{1}{4}(2a_n+n+2).$

So finally, I can punch $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}(2a_n+n+2)$ into my calculator and pray that it generates a table or something.

However, I think I can go farther. I think I could solve the recurrence relation.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: $a_n={n\over2} + 2^{-n}$, but what's the point? You could just as well solve the differential equation instead, like you said.

Comment: @IvanNeretin i have to use euler's method, so skipping the number crunching and using recursion

Comment: Then go on, but that's a very artificial setting anyway. Normally, if the differential equation is not easily solvable, the recurrence relation won't help either.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I wasn't actually concerned about the differential equation, but for a math test setting, where I have to take 20 steps of size h=0.05, say. In that setting, it would be helpful to use a recurrence relation to bypass all the decimal crunching